# WP создание кастомной таблицы в БД. Назначение дефолтных значений

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Пробую создать кастомную таблицу в WordPress в соответствии с [рекомендациями](https://wp-kama.ru/function/dbdelta).
Таблица в базе должна состоять из двух столбцов `json` и `object_last_modified` после создания столбци должны содержать какие-то дефолтные значения, которые можно б было обновить.

```
function create_table()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}
                ( json LONGTEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                  {$charset_collate}
                  ";
                  dbDelta($sql);
            }
        }
        create_table();
```

Этот код почему-то не работает. Хотя если создавать с отпутывающими начальными значениями по типу.

```
function create_table()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}
                ( json LONGTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE  utf8_general_ci,
                  object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                  {$charset_collate}
                  ";
                  dbDelta($sql);
            }

        }
        create_table();
```

То создание происходит. Подскажите, как должен выглядеть код для такой задачи?

---

То что вышло после обсуждения

```
 function create_table()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

            $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
            $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

            if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

                $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}
                ( json LONGTEXT NOT NULL default '0',
                  object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
                INSERT INTO {$table_name} (json, object_last_modified)
                VALUES ('0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
                  {$charset_collate}";
                dbDelta($sql);
            }
        }

        create_table();
```

Comment: Потому что в первом примере кода есть ряд ошибок. 1. `json LONGTEXT NOT NULL COLLATE default '0'`, а именно `COLLATE default '0'`, после `COLLATE` должно быть `utf8_general_ci` либо просто уберите `COLLATE`, так как Вы в принципе уже используете при создании таблицы `$charset_collate`. 2. Определитесь, у Вас по дефолту должно быть `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` или все же  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: 1. Убрал 2. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP нужен.

Comment: 2. Ну тогда оставьте `object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, как во втором примере, потому что в первом у Вас и то и другое `object_last_modified timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Ну и имейте ввиду, что эти дефолтные значения применяются при добавлении новой строки в таблицу (если нет значения), это не значит что таблица будет создана с уже заполненным определенным количеством строк с дефолтными значениями. Вам просто нужно после создания таблицы сделать [INSERT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем тогда вообще нужен этот функционал с `default` значением, если всё равно необходимо выполнение дополнительного запроса. Я поменял код примера (3) но мне непонятно, что есть value для 'object_last_modified' ?

Comment: Ну как зачем. Если Вы добавляете новую строку в БД и например, в Вашем случае, Вы добавляете новую строку и указываете только значение для колнки `json`, то значение в колонку `object_last_modified` будет добавлена автоматически. [SQL DEFAULT Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp). "Что есть value для 'object_last_modified?" -- CURRENT_TIMESTAMP и будет DEFAULT значением, то есть при добавлении строки будет добавлен CURRENT_TIMESTAMP вида `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

Comment: Ясно, тогда если вернуться к первоначальному вопросу с добавлением после создания базы дефолтных значений посредствам `INSERT INTO` -> Почему код не записывает в базу указанные значения? В чем синтаксическая ошибка?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140010/discussion-between-simon-and-blackstar1991).